# htaccess rule return funny results in $_GET variable

Tags: .htaccess

this is a snippet of my htaccess, at the bottom is the redirect for user accounts.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews 
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /core/error/templates/404/

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico favicon.ico [NC,L]
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# RewriteRules
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# User profile redirect
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$       /user/$1 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

if i go to www.foo.bar/samsam it should populate the `$_GET['user']` with `"samsam"` but when i do an echo it actually returns `$_GET['user'] = profile.php`

any ideas as to why its behaving this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you need a couple of fixes to that last line.  You'll need to remove the leading "/" character in your regexp.  You'll also need to filter your last `RewriteRule` so it only affects non-existent files and directories.  So... replace it with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: i have the !-d and !-f declared near the top of my snippet, does that make a difference? also  i tried that but when i go to foo.bar/index.php with treats that as a GET variable. i was able to get it to work with this ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L] not sure why tho

Comment: Yeah, you do need the !-d and !-f declared again.  When it encounters RewriteRule, it clears all previous RewriteCond statements.  In other words, RewriteCond only applies until it his the next RewriteRule statement.

Comment: I think the confusion partly stems from that first Rewrite block.  May I ask -- why is it there?  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Ah, I see.  If foo.bar/index.php doesn't exist, that first Rewrite block would add a "/" to the end.  Then when it tried to load that, the second Rewrite block caught it and assumed it was a username.  That's why it worked to change the regular expression on the second Rewrite block so it wouldn't catch strings with a "." in them (such as your "index.php".)